# XmlReader leaving xml file open?

Tags: c#, xml, save

I have an XML file that looks a bit like this:

```
<Paths>
    <Path>
        <Other stuff be here/>
    </Path>
</Paths>
```

I want to programmatically add a new "Path" node after the current one, still within the "Paths" node. Here's what I'm trying:

```
XmlDocument xmlDoc = new XmlDocument();
string xmlFilePath = "ThatFileFromAbove.xml";
using (XmlReader reader = XmlReader.Create(xmlFilePath))
xmlDoc.Load(reader);
XmlNode newPathNode = xmlDoc.CreateNode(XmlNodeType.Element, "Path", "Test");
xmlDoc.GetElementsByTagName("Paths")[0]
   .InsertAfter(newPathNode, xmlDoc.GetElementsByTagName("Paths")[0].LastChild);
xmlDoc.Save(xmlFilePath);
```

I end up getting an exception:

> "The process cannot access the file because it is being used by another process."

This occurs on the `xmlDoc.Save` line. Clearly the reader is still open, and I cannot figure out how to close the reader before saving.

Comment: Are you sure it *isn't* opened by some other process -- the one that created it for example?  After fixing your XML and saving it with Notepad, I can't reproduce your bug.  Note that if the file is locked for writing by another process, it might still be openable for reading.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I tried you code it is correct. However your XML is not, the end should be closing a `<Paths>` element not `<Path>`

```
<Paths>
    <Path>
        <!-- Other stuff be here -->
    </Path>
</Paths>
```

Also make sure that the file really is not used in another process.
You can use process explorer tool to find it out. (http://windowsxp.mvps.org/processlock.htm)

Result XML:

```
<Paths>
    <Path>
        <!-- Other stuff be here -->
    </Path>
    <Path xmlns="Test" />
</Paths>
```

Comment: Thank you for pointing out the "Path"/"Paths" typo (I've edited my question to be correct). Turns out I read the file earlier in the application and forgot to close() the reader... *facepalm* I'm marking this answer as accepted as the process explorer led me to the solution.